# Creating a page with php to display a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I apologise if this isn't clear what I want but I'll do my best.

I'm currently an IT apprentice and have been asked to create a complaints database. I decided to create a table and echo data to a table just to create a quick summary of the complaints received,

```
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>CAN No</th>
<th>Contract No</th>
<th>Customer</th>
<th>Supplier</th>
<th>Date filed</th>
<th>Raised by</th>
<th>Details</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>

<?php while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><? print $db_field['can_no'] ?></td>
<td><? print $db_field['contract_no'] ?></td>
<td><? print $db_field['customer'] ?></td>
<td><? print $db_field['supplier'] ?></td>
<td><? print $db_field['datemade'] ?></td>
<td><? print $db_field['raised_by'] ?></td>
<td><? print $db_field['details'] ?></td>
<td> View » </td>
<td> Edit » </td>
<td> Delete [x] </td>
</tr>
```

So this just creates a quick summary of the complaints received. (I will add a search function at some point). What I now want to add is a way to view the whole complaint in a format I like and not a table. For example I click view on View for one of them and it takes to me www.website.com/complaints?id=1 and this would display the full complaint on a whole different page.

Also, how would I get the edit button to bring up the same page with data already filled so it can be quickly edited?

Sorry if I haven't explained it well :(

Edit: I found out how to do what I wanted and got it working perfectly. I created complaints.php and used $_GET['id'] and then used SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE id = '$id'.

Thanks everyone who helped.

Comment: try and upgrade to `mysqli_` or `PDO` to connect to MySql database. `mysql_` is old

Comment: You actually explained well but it's too much to ask. We might end up doing everything for you

Comment: @codingbiz I will look into using them. For now I'm just going to stick with `mysql` till I've finished then I will look at going back and using `mysqli_` or `PDO`. Also, I'm not asking you do to do it for me, I just want to know how it's done or some links that explain it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Look into this on google

- How to pass id and get it through query string
- How to pre-populate data from database

Those two should help you

Your view should be 
    `echo('<a href="www.website.com/complaints?id=' . $db_field['details'] . '">View</a>');`

Help:  $_GET, $_POST

```
$id = (int)$_GET['complaint_id'];  // Where id MUST be an integer
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Complaint WHERE complaint_id = $id";
execute your query
```

That is probably a bad code, but just to explain.

Also read about  [SQL-Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

> **Warning:**
>
> Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)?
>
> Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should give some details about deciding which API to use. For PDO, here is a [good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

At first, you should read more about [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) as this is a very **insecure** way to do it.

For the *View* part, you can set up a different page to view an individual complaint, with modifying the text to `<a href="view_complaint.php?id= <?php print $db_field['id']; ?>">View</a>`. (I am assuming your database setup to contain an `id` field here.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE complaint_id = $id");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Now you have an `$row` array with the same fields you can output in a HTML format you would like to. No need for a `while` construct as we only have one row.

`www.website.com/complaints?id=1` is a bit dodgy, as this is not really a proper URL. You either make use of [nice URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nice+url) to set up `website.com/complaints/1`, or you use a PHP file in your website root: `website.com/complaints.php?id=1`.

For edition and deleteion, if you don't want a page reload for the edition, [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is what you will need. This will help you to set up an approach where the browser does not need to reload the page to modify the content. You'll need to know JavaScript for this, and before you do, get familiar with deeper PHP too and **secure your already existing code**.

For the non-asychronous part. You can make a page which handles the edition with passing the same `?id=1` parameter in its request. This site should contain as many `<input>` fields in a form as much fields are in the database. Every `<input>` field takes a `value="foobar"` attribute which sets its default value. Just like how you print the content into the table now, you can put it on pageload into the form, where you can edit it as you want. And when the form is sent, you will use the `UPDATE table SET field1=value1, field2=value2 WHERE id = $id` query to update your database.

I can only suggest to you that you at first make your system be able to handle edits and deletes even if it requires invoking a seperate page and an extra request from the client, and then move on to the asynchronous approach.

Comment: Thank you for you help and I apologise for my slow reply. This really helped, I will work on using `mysqli` once I have finished then revamp it.